# Unobtrusive attributes not returning true for file input in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have created a HtmlHelper to render unobtrusive data attributes on a file input. This this is working perfectly in Firefox, but is not working in IE 8.

```
<input id="Attachment" type="file"name="Attachment" 
    data-val-required="The Attachment field is required." 
    data-val-iswhitelistedfile-whitelist="jpeg,jpg,gif,tif,png,bmp,pdf,doc,docx,rtf,odt,xls,xlsx,ods,ppt,pptx,odp,txt,csv,mp3,mp4,msg" 
    data-val-iswhitelistedfile="Invalid file extension. Only the following file extensions are allowed: jpeg, jpg, gif, tif, png, bmp, pdf, doc, docx, rtf, odt, xls, xlsx, ods, ppt, pptx, odp, txt, csv, mp3, mp4, msg" 
    data-val-isvalidfilename-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{1,244}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}$" 
    data-val-isvalidfilename="Invalid Filename. Filenames may only include letters, numbers, spaces, underscores and hyphens, plus a single full stop and file extension (for example 'My File.pdf') and may not be more than 255 characters in total" 
    data-val="true">
```

It appears that the inbuilt `Required` javascript works to get the value from the input in Firefox, but not in IE8. If I remove the required attribute, but submit an invalid filename, the client validation will not fail (the filename check does not require there to be a value). I had to update my js files to the latest version to get any validation to work. I am using the MVC 5.2.3 unobtrusive validation, jquery 1.11.0 and jquery.validate 1.13.0.

Obviously I could adapt my whitelist check to cater for required/not required, but I was hoping to use the existing functionality. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this.